# node_redis AbortError trying to delete multiple keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

So i have the following code, and i cannot get seem to delete multiple keys. I have been able to delete multiple keys before with this lib. Is it because it's nested in an mget?

```
client.mget(keyArray, function (err, res) {
        if(err){
            deferred.reject(err);
        }else{
            // do some things with those keys and their values


            //now remove the keys, dont need anymore
            client.del(keyArray, function(err, count){
                if(err){
                    console.log('Error deleting redis keys: ');
                    console.log(err);
                    deferred.reject(err);
                    return;
                }

                console.log('Deleted Redis keys : ' + count);


                deferred.resolve(response);

            }); 
        }
    });
```

I run the code for a keyArray of exactly 1000 length.

I see an error that says

```
[2017-02-01 20:14:49.111] [INFO] info - { AbortError
at handle_offline_command (/Users/me/workspace/thingProject/node_modules/redis/index.js:846:15)
at RedisClient.internal_send_command (/Users/me/workspace/thingProject/node_modules/redis/index.js:880:9)
at RedisClient.del (/Users/me/workspace/thingProject/node_modules/redis/lib/commands.js:62:25)
at Command.callback (/Users/me/workspace/thingProject/bulkUploader.js:414:24)
at normal_reply (/Users/mr/workspace/thingProject/node_modules/redis/index.js:721:21)
at RedisClient.return_reply (/Users/me/workspace/thingProject/node_modules/redis/index.js:819:9)
at JavascriptRedisParser.returnReply (/Users/me/workspace/thingProject/node_modules/redis/index.js:192:18)
at JavascriptRedisParser.execute (/Users/me/workspace/thingProject/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:539:10)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/me/workspace/thingProject/node_modules/redis/index.js:274:27)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:551:20)
command: 'DEL',
code: 'NR_CLOSED',
args: 
 [ 'create:thing:508836',
   'create:thing:511906',
   'create:thing:441525',
  ...
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. I'm not entirely sure how to interpret this error message.

-Kirby